# Excluding items from dictionary in for loop and using if and else with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am creating a simple form. I wish to create a dropdown for the Transaction key in the dictionary rather than Entry in for-loop. Is it possible to exclude items of dictionary in for-loop and can we use if-else statement with dictionary? Thanks in advance and open to all kinds of suggestions:

```
from tkinter import *

at = Tk()

# Creating title and geometry

at.title("Add Transaction")
at.geometry('500x500+500+150')

# Defining lists for labels

at_list = {
    "Broker:": StringVar(),
    "Transaction:": StringVar(),
    "Date:": StringVar(),
    "Symbol:": StringVar(),
    "Name:": StringVar(),
    "Quantity:": StringVar(),
    "Amount:": StringVar(),
    "Total Amount of share:": StringVar(),
    "Brokerage:": StringVar(),
    "Taxes:": StringVar(),
    "Total Amount:": StringVar()
}

# Creating labels

counter = 0
for i in at_list:
    at_label = "at_" + i
    at_label = Label(at, text=i)
    at_label.grid(row=counter, column=0, sticky=W)
    counter += 1

# Creating entries

counter = 0
for i in at_list:
    at_entry = 'entry_' + i
    at_entry = Entry(at, width=30, textvariable=at_list[i])
    at_entry.grid(row=counter, column=1, sticky=E)
    counter += 1

at.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are asking. Can you post examples of the current results and what you want to have instead?

Comment: I mean, keeping the same code, I don't wish to create an entry for all the labels as defined in the dictionary. So how to add an exception for a certain item in the dictionary. One way I found is to use if statement stating "if counter == 1:" and rest in an "else:" statement

Comment: Please try to limit SO questions to a specific issue/question. Asking multiple questions makes it difficult to have one singular answer worth anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be h helpful, dic_name.items() function.
eg
dic_name={'a':1,'b':2}
for key,val in dic_name.items():
    print(key,val)